# How to handle Insert and Delete requests arriving out of order?

Tags: distributed-systems, concurrency

Entries need to be stored in a database. There is `Insert(entry)` RPC, which adds a new entry in a database, and `Delete(entry)` RPC, which deletes an existing entry from a database. Neither RPC can be blocking, because that adds undesired latency. Both RPCs are scheduled to run asynchronously when required, from different places in code, thus one RPC doesn't know if another has succeeded.

The problem happens, when `Insert(entry)` RPC is supposed happen before `Delete(entry)` RPC, but due to various reasons (e.g. network latency), the RPCs arrive out of order. First `Delete(entry)` deletes a non-existing entry (no op), then `Insert(entry)` request arrives, sees that the entry does not exist, and inserts it. The end result is that we have an orphaned entry which wasn't supposed to be in the database.

What are typical solutions to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing is that both Insert and Delete report exactly what has happened, so the caller can react.

Second, design the Delete call so that it needs to pass for example the ID of a record. The Insert call would insert the record, create a new ID for it, and report that ID. As a result, you cannot call Delete until after you received the ID from a successful Insert call.

If Insert / Delete use some external key that is unique, then a Delete for a record that hasn't been inserted yet is possible. The Delete call could return that it failed because there was no record with that key, and the caller could retry the Delete sometime later.

As a complex alternative, Delete checks if the record is there and either deletes it, or stores a marker in the database that some key needs to be deleted. The Insert operation first looks for this marker, and if present, removes the marker instead of inserting the key. Insert and Delete would return what exactly happened, so after an error free "Insert" call the caller knows whether or not the record is there.